# Can't reach Azure App Service from within my private LAN on a windows machine

Tags: windows, networking, dns, azure-web-app-service

This morning I noticed that none of the web apps I am running in Azure is reachable anymore.
I first thought its an issue with Azure itself, but when I try to connect with a mobile hotspot (through my phone) everything works as expected.
The problem seems only to exist in my own LAN at home but only Azure is affected.

When I try to navigate to a website, I get the following message:

[image]

I also cannot nslookup it:

[image]

I do not have any problem with surfing the internet. All other sites work fine... but I don't even know where to start on solving this problem.
Does anybody know a tool to diagnose this? What could be wrong here...?

I did not have any issues with accessing the services yesterday.

Comment: Definitely a DNS issue. Since the mobile hotspot works, it must be providing a different DNS server through DHCP to your PC. You could try manually setting a DNS server (like the Google 8.8.8.8 server mentioned in the answer) in the network configuration on your PC and see if that makes it work.

Comment: It was a DNS issue... it resolved itself just waiting for a day... strange. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent years, DNS has become the most vulnerable part of the internet, as many other components are strengthened significantly.

Like you discovered, for some unknown reasons the DNS your machine connects to failed to sync the proper Azure related records. That's not an uncommon issue if you read about how badly DNS infrastructure around the globe was maintained.

Usual solutions are,

- Switch to other DNS service than your default ISP provided ones, Google/Cloudflare public DNS servers are popular, and there are many other good options.
- Hack your `hosts` file (but that's too complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Since you had no Problems yesterday, my first question is: Did you change anything in your local Network?

Maybe some new Firewall rules or maybe some entry in your Host File for testing?

When you try to access Azure with only the IP, does that work? If yes then you have to look at your DNS.(maybe try Google DNS 8.8.8.8)

Comment: I did not change anything... it just stopped working on all devices that are in my private LAN. It must be a DNS thing, because if I enter the IP address, I can reach the app service... very strange. It cannot be the host file, because it stopped working on all devices...